# How to use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass within a JerseyTest suite

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

It turns out that JUnit wants `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` to be static and this doesn't get along well with JerseyTest's `configure` method override. Is there a known way to configure the Jersey application while still being able to access JUnit's utility methods?

```
public class MyControllerTest  extends JerseyTest {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() throws Exception {
    target("myRoute").request().post(Entity.json("{}"));
  }
  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
      return new AppConfiguration();
  }
}
```

Hence `beforeClass` needs to be static, `target` cannot be called because of its instance-method nature. While trying to use the constructor instead, it turns out that `configure` is run after the `constructor` and this prevents the setup-request to be executed and will therefor fail naturally.

Any advice is more than appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, why would you want the `setup()` method to be static in the first place? Can't you just make it a member and use `@Before` instead?

Comment: Didi  you try `@Before` instead of `@BeforeClass` ?

Comment: it's meant to be a heavy and potentially time consuming operation which i don't want to run on each single test. @Dimitri

Comment: JUnit whats `@BeforeClass` methods to be static, it's not a matter of choice unfortunately @hfhc2

Comment: Another solution is  to define a Junit Rule and use the annotation @ClassRule.

Comment: thanks for the advice, could you put that into an answer? @Dimitri

Answer (score 1):

What we did in several cases to avoid heavy setups in such situations is to use a boolean flag to run that setup conditionally.

```java
public class MyControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

  private static myRouteSetupDone = false;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    if (!myRouteSetupDone) {
      target("myRoute").request().post(Entity.json("{}"));
      myRouteSetupDone = true;
    }
  }
  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
      return new AppConfiguration();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**@Before** does not require the *static* modifier and will be executed before every test-method.

Comment: it's meant to be a heavy and potentially time consuming operation which i don't want to run on each single test.